# How to remove spaces from date time string in c

Tags: c, string

The code below creates a string with date and time for example `Wed Jul 26 14:45:28 2017`

How could I remove the spaces from it? So that is is `WedJul2614:45:28`?

Original code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    char s[64];
    strftime(s, sizeof(s), "%c", tm);
    printf("%s\n", s);
}
```

I tried this code but it prints `wed?July`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    char s[64];
    char temp[64];
    strftime(s, sizeof(s), "%c", tm);
    printf("%s\n", s);


    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(s); i++) {
      if (s[i] != ' ') {
        temp[i] = s[i];
      }
    }
printf("%s\n", temp);  
}
```

Comment: You're not copying anything when encountering space characters, so when you print out `temp` the characters you see there are at the mercy of what was allocated for you (for example, the `?` character). You should use another index to keep track of how far you are in to `temp` so you make sure the "holes" are filled in. You should also make sure `temp` is properly null-terminated when you're finished copying.

Comment: Two problems: You use uninitialized elements of `s` since you use `sizeof` instead of `strlen` to get the length of the string in `s`. The other is you basically make a straight string copy from `s` to `temp` *except* where `s` contains a space, where you leave the corresponding element in `temp` *uninitialized*.

Comment: Why don't you replace your format string `"%c"` by a string that only includes the fields you want without spaces? Like `"%a%b%d%T"`

Comment: Again a perfect opportunity to learn how to use debugger and trace through the program line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is *really* going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Answer (score 6):

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; s[i]!='\0'; i++) {
  if (s[i] != ' ') {
    temp[j] = s[i];
    j++;
  }
}
```

Keep track of the index so you don't just leave the spaces with some random value. Also, you should add a null at the end of temp.

```
temp[j] = '\0';
```

Comment: @chux I think what you're suggesting is an improvement.

Answer (score 4):

Matt's answer works but you can do it too:

This exemple is without call to system function: strlen. Here we don't need it. It's a bit optimize.

```
i = 0;
int j = 0;
while (s[i] != '\0')
  {
    if (s[i] == ' ')
      {
        temp[j] = s[i];
        j++;
      }
    i++;
  }
temp[j] = '\0';
```

Don't forget the '\0' at the end of your string.

Answer (score 2):

Matt already provided an answer for what you *asked*.

What you probably *want* or *need* can also be achieved a bit easier.
If you don't want spaces, just avoid adding them in the first place:

Replace your format string `"%c"` for `strftime()` which provides standard format for your locale with a string that creates directly what you want: `"%a%b%d%T"`

Comment: If the string came from `asctime()`, there is no `"%c"` to replace.

Comment: Ah yes, true enough.

Comment: This has the advantage that the original `char s[64];` may be smaller/less chance of overrun.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more expensive, but you at least do not need another variable and as well have a valid string on each modification.

```
#include <string.h>

...

  size_t l = strlen(s);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    if (s[i] != ' ') {
      memmove(s+i, s+i+1, l-i+1); 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can squeeze spaces out in place, using standard library functions. Given that the string is very short and there's only a few spaces, performance won't suffer much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
    char s[64];
    strftime(s, sizeof(s), "%c", tm);
    printf("before: %s\n", s);

    for ( char *p = strchr(s, ' '); p ;  p = strchr(p, ' ') )
        strcpy(p, p+1);

   printf("after: %s\n",s);

}
```